# How do I set the margin to bottom of a chart in HighCharts to zero?

Tags: highcharts

demo:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/wmgbbp9k/show/

[image]

Is it possible to set this margin to zero?

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation is pretty thorough:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: highcharts docs are anything but. 404 city, https upgrade issues, and not to mention the number of variables and techniques that cannot be found in the documentation, but can be found here. these may well be in the documentation, but search is such a pos, you can't put in any term they don't have a value for. its horrible.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that by setting margins and  spacingBottom in chart config

```
 chart: {

        marginLeft: 0,
        marginBottom: 0,
        marginTop: 0,
        marginRight: 0,
       spacingBottom:
    }
```

[Please refer documentation here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style)

Comment: thanks. but it seems i have to set the marginbottom to negative numbers to make it looks 0.